# Not able to check file size while uploading multiple files in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to check file size limit for Multiple file upload.Each and every time i receive **Sorry, your file is too large upload, maximum file size is 10 MB.** 
not able to figure out the mistake.

without providing the file limit the file upload is working fine. I have also made the necessary changes in the PHP.ini file like POST_MAX_SIZE and MAX_FILE_SIZE still the response is same.

```
foreach($_FILES['upload_slider']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
                #file upload size - file size 10MB
                $fileSize = $_FILES['upload_slider']['size'][$key];
                if ($fileSize <= 10485760) #10 MB 
                {

                    $_SESSION['upload_warning'] = "Sorry, your file is too large upload, maximum file size is 10 MB.";
                    header("location:../slider.php");
                    die;            
                }


            else{
                $file_name = strtolower($_FILES['upload_slider']['name'][$key]);
                $file_tmp = $_FILES['upload_slider']['tmp_name'][$key];
                $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $new_filename = rand().".".$ext;
                if(in_array($ext,$extension))
                {
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp= $_FILES['upload_slider']['tmp_name'][$key],"$album_dir$new_filename");
                    # insert record in database

                    $values = [
                    'slider_id' =>$slider_id,
                    'image_name' => $new_filename,
                    //'album_name' => $album_title,
                    'image_path' => $db_album_dir.$new_filename,
                    'uploaded_date' => date("Y/m/d h:i:s ")
                    ];
                    $res = $abc->insert($tablename,$values);                
                    header("location:../slider.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['upload_warning'] = "Please upload appropriate file type extension i.e. <b> jpg, jpeg, png , gif. </b> ";
                    header("location:../slider.php");
                    die;
                }
            }

        }//EOF FROEACH
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to limit every file to 10Mb? Because right now your if statement says the opposite:

```
if ($fileSize <= 10485760){ //if the file is less or equal to 10mb
//return error
}
else{ //else if the file is larger than 10mb
//proceed with uploading
}
```

So you should try it like this:

```
if($fileSize >= 10485760){ //return error
}
else { //upload file
}
```

Comment: what kind of operator is this => ?

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake, meant to write `>=` (greater than or equal), but wrote `=>` which is a separator for associative arrays. Fixed in the post right now.
Associative array looks like this:
`$user_list = array(
    'name' => 'john',
    'surname' => 'white'
);`

Instead of an index (numbers 0-n) it has 'keys' (in this case name, surname) assigned to values (john, white).